# Matplotlib axes step and range of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have code for plotting like this:

```
def plotMaker(self):
    self.d_time ...
    self.d_altitude  ...
    self.min = 0
    self.max = 2198
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(self.d_time, self.d_altitude)
    plt.xlabel('time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('height')
    plt.title('Title')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig("high.png")
    return fig
```

And first value of d_time is 0 and last is 2198
(depends on values `self.min` and   `self.max`). So this is range of my data

But my plot looks like this:

[image: plot image]

and max value of plot is 2500. There is some blank space without values due to plot step 500. Is it possible to change range of this plot to `self.min` and   `self.max` or maybe change the step?

Comment: `plt.ylim((0,2200))` and `plt.yticks((0,1000,2000,2200))`

Comment: and what I need to import? because `'module' object has no attribute 'ytics'`

Comment: and also `s/y/x/` ... I had somehow misunderstood your choice of axes!

Comment: Yes, I fixed it in my code :D Thanks, it works like it should!